# make alias for ls so that it doesn't show files of the pattern *~

Tags: bash, grep, alias, ls

Is there a series of commands that does ls then removes backup files? I want to do something like

```
ls | grep -v *~
```

but this shows all the files in different lines, any one to make the output identical to ls?

When I type in "man ls" My man page for ls has this option of -B its

```
   -B      Force printing of non-printable characters (as defined by ctype(3)
           and current locale settings) in file names as \xxx, where xxx is the
           numeric value of the character in octal.
```

It is not identical to the one you showed and I searched for ignored but no results popped up. Btw I am on a mac, which might have a different version of ls?

Alternatively, can I tell a directory to stop making backup files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all files ending in `~` with:

```
ls -d *[^~]
```

The `*[^~]` specifies all files that don't end in `~`.  The `-d` flag tells `ls` not to show the directory contents for any directories that it matches (as with the default `ls` command).

**Edit:** If you alias your `ls` to use the command above, it will break the standard `ls` usage, so you're better off using ephemient's solution if you want your `ls` usage to always exclude backup files.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `ls` from GNU coreutils,

```
       -B, --ignore-backups
              do not list implied entries ending with ~
```

You can also set `FIGNORE='~'` in Bash so that `*` never expands to contain filenames ending in `~`.

Comment: +1, great solution.  I actually just realized that this is much better than my approach because it doesn't break `ls` usage if you alias `ls -B` as `ls`.

Comment: There's also `-I, --ignore=PATTERN`.

Comment: You can also `shopt -s extglob` and then say `ls !(*~)`

Comment: I have some problems with this solution look at my follow up question.

Comment: @Doboy Then your `ls` is of BSD heritage.  As stated, this only works for GNU coreutils.  With BSD `ls`, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For people forced to use `ls` that doesn't have `-B`  (e.g., using BSD ls in Mac OS X), you can create an alias to a bash function that is based on Mansoor Siddiqui's suggestion.  If you add the following function to your bash profile where you keep your aliases (`.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_aliases`, or equivalent):

```
ls_no_hidden() {
  nonflagcount=0
  ARG_ARRAY=(${@})
  flags="-l"
  curdir=`pwd`
  shopt -s nullglob
  # Iterate through args, find all flags (arg starting with dash (-))
  for (( i = 0; i < $# ; i++ )); do
    if [[ ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]} == -* ]]; then
      flags="${flags} ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]}";
    else
      ((nonflagcount++));
    fi
  done

  if [[ $nonflagcount -eq 0 ]]; then
    # ls current directory if no non-flag args provided
    FILES=`echo *[^~#]` 
    # check if files are present, before calling ls 
    # to suppress errors if no matches.
    if [[ -n $FILES ]]; then
      ls $flags -d *[^~#]
    fi
  else
    # loop through all args, and run ls for each non-flag
    for (( i = 0; i < $# ; i++ )); do
      if [[ ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]} != -* ]]; then
        # if directory, enter the directory
        if [[ -d ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]} ]]; then
          cd ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]}
          # check that the cd was successful before calling ls
          if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
            pwd # print directory you are listing (feel free to comment out)
            FILES=`echo *[^~#]`
            if [[ -n $FILES ]]; then
              ls $flags -d *[^~#]
            fi
            cd $curdir
          fi
        else
          # if file list the file
          if [[ -f ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]} ]]; then
            ls $flags ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]}
          else
            echo "Directory/File not found: ${ARG_ARRAY[${i}]}"
          fi
        fi
      fi
    done
  fi
}
alias l=ls_no_hidden
```

Then `l` will be mapped to `ls` but not show files that end in `~` or `#`.